# Ligatures disabling

Tags: ligatures

I want to disable ligatures when I am typing letters, however, I need '--' to be joined to a long dash. Is it possible to make this?

Now I am avoiding it like this

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = * }
```

Comment: Use `\textendash` for the en-dash.

Comment: Why is it better than just type double dash?

Comment: If you disable *all* ligatures, that command will use the en dash anyway.

Comment: Links to some related questions, if some future reader come across this question: [microtype - How can I completely suppress ligatures? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/how-can-i-completely-suppress-ligatures), https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61042/suppress-certain-ligatures-generally?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/how-do-i-prevent-latex-from-creating-en-dash-and-em-dash?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can only do it the other way round as described in the documentation of `microtype`. You can give a list of chars for which ligatures should be disabled:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = * }
\begin{document}
fi ---

\end{document}
```

Comment: For me, the above did not work for disabling ligatures in source code listings with a tt font. However, `\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = tt* }` did work (as suggested in the microtype manual).