# LaTeX and Word - how to convert

Tags: format-files

One of our chemistry professors asked us to convert our LaTeX document into PDF, because it's easier for him to correct the document that way. I just thought it was impossible to convert Word to LaTeX and LaTeX to Word - but he is a professor on "Science an Technology" so I think he should know what LaTeX is. So is their any possibilty to create a Word document of LaTeX?

Comment: Which is it: PDF or Word? Your question mentions both.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it's not possible without a lot of manual work. Since he obviously doesn't care about quality of output, what about a conversion TeX => PDF => HTML => Word? Might be worth a shot.

Comment: @Ingmar that may work but only if you [disable ligatures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57718/ligatures-disabling) - newer acrobat readers can deal with some but not all

Comment: I've found it less awful to write LaTeX in word than to go the other way (i.e. \label, \ref, \cite etc. and import equations from a parallel LaTeX document as images). But if he wants PDF that's easy, don't touch word at all.