# Wrong glyph and wrong ligature with FiraMono and listings

Tags: listings, typewriter

Consider the following MWE:

```
% Compile with pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces=true
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\ifx\foo\baz
\fi
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: listing]

Why is the backslash rendered as double-quote? And how to disable the `fi` ligature? Note that these two problems disappear if one compiles the above MWE with XeLaTeX.

---

Reasons for `columns=fullflexible`: The default `columns=fixed` puts each character in a box of fixed width `0.6em`. Coincidentally, `0.6em` happens to be the width of a character from Fira Mono. But for other typefaces, the widths differ. The option `columns=fullflexible` sets each character to its natural width, which is desired.

Comment: For the backslashes: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: For the ligatures maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57718/35864 can help ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `microtype` package to disable ligatures for all `tt` fonts.  This will also disable kerning for that particular font, but that's usually unwanted for typewriter text anyway.

For the backslash, the default OT1 encoding does not have enough slots, so it is not mapped.  Using T1 encoding fixes the problem.

```
% Compile with pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces=true
}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = tt* }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\ifx\foo\baz
\fi
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]